# DC/DC Buck Converter : Implementing Convenient Minor Alterations to Output Voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, feedback, tuning

### Question

How can I perform precision minor output voltage adjustments when using a dc/dc voltage buck converter with high efficiency (including at light loads), without loss of efficiency and without manufacturing rework (resoldering parts)?

### Rough Specifications

```
V.in    = (V.usb.min to V.batt.max )
V.in    = +04.75 — +12.60 [V]

V.out   = (V.out.typ to V.out.max  )
V.out.r = +02.90 ( —> +03.00 ) —> +03.10 [V]
V.out.g = +03.50 ( —> +03.60 ) —> +03.70 [V]
V.out.b = +03.70 ( —> +03.80 ) —> +03.90 [V]
I.out   = +00.00 —  +00.75 [A]

n.effcy ≥ +00.90          [-] (for I.out ≥ 0.001 [A] )
```

### Known Considerations (Likely Undesirable)

- Converter feedback resistor: Potentiometer (standard)

  - Imprecise
  - Lossy
- Converter feedback resistor: Potentiometer (digital)

  - Pricey (if precision desired)
- LDO (linear voltage converter) output of switching converter

  - Lossy
- Power converter with programmable output

  - Ex: [TPS63810](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS63810) (V.in.max too low for me, but cool.)
  - Ex: [MAX77857](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max77857.html) (Efficiency too low for me, but cool!)

### Known Considerations (Potentially Desirable)

- Converter feedback resistor: Parallel path(s) to resistor + removable jumper/MOSFET

  - Considerable?
  - **Could this adversely affect feedback readings?**

### Suggested Considerations (Must read further)

- "dip switches and R2R"

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150350/discussion-on-question-by-kando-dc-dc-buck-converter-implementing-convenient-m); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.